# Статический метод абстрактного класса, С++

Tags: c++, наследование, static

Есть вот такое условие задачи:

1 Создать массив из шести объектов (по два каждого производного класса).

2 Вывести объекты на консоль через Show().

3 Отсортировать объекты по убыванию.

4 Вывести объекты на консоль через Show().

Есть абстрактный базовый класс, к примеру, class A. От него наследуются два класса, пусть это будет class B & class C.

При выполнении условия 1(создать массив из 6 объектов) я использую std::vector вот таким образом: `vector<unique_ptr>A> arr`;

Далее через функцию push.pack() добавляю в него нужное количество объектов.

И вот есть массив из 6 объектов. У каждого из производных классов есть свой метод Show(), который они переопределяют своей реализацией. НО, метод это не статический, а должен быть таковым (т.к. есть условие, что метод Show() нужно сделать статическим). В чем, собственно, вопрос: как мне в этой ситуации сделать метод Show() статическим? Я, честно говоря, сталкивался с работой только со статическими переменными, но не функциями. Еще есть условие, что метод Show() должен вызываться в цикле по созданному массиву.

P.S. Понимаю, что такое статическая функция и т.д. Но не могу написать реализацию для этого случая.

Comment: если коротко - вопрос как создать статический метод? Если да, то https://ideone.com/dtCpxC например.

Comment: @pavel, я понимаю как сделать метод статическим, не понимаю как это сделать для моего случая. Тут мне нужно будет потом вызвать этот метод в цикле по созданному массиву,а что передавать в качестве аргументов в статическую функцию тогда? или она должна быть без аргументов? или она должна быть только у базового класса и не переопределяться в производных? я вот просто не знаю про это. + ко всему массив указателей на объекты.

Comment: статическую функцию нельзя переопределить в производном классе.

Comment: @pavel,окей, тогда как сделать, чтобы статическая функция могла учитывать те изменения, которые будут внесены при реализации определенных методов классов-потомков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A
{
public:
    static void show(const A* object)
    {
        object->show();
    }

    virtual void show() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void show() const override
    {
        std::cout << "hello from B" << std::endl;
    }

};

class C : public A
{
public:
    void show() const override
    {
        std::cout << "hello from C" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> arr;

    arr.push_back(new B());
    arr.push_back(new C());

    for (const auto& it : arr)
        A::show(it);

    return 0;
}
```

так не подойдет?)

UPD1:

```
class A
{
public:
    static void show(const std::unique_ptr<A>& object)
    {
        object->show();
    }

    virtual void show() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void show() const override
    {
        std::cout << "hello from B" << std::endl;
    }

};

class C : public A
{
public:
    void show() const override
    {
        std::cout << "hello from C" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> arr;

    arr.push_back(std::make_unique<B>());
    arr.push_back(std::make_unique<C>());

    for (const auto& it : arr)
        A::show(it);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Классно, спасибо, то, что искал!

Comment: @Koka_LV, в общем случае статик метод на то и статик, что он существует отдельно от объектов и может быть вызван без создания объекта. В данном случае статик метод класса А будет дергать виртуальный метод. В теории можно извратиться и реализовать на шаблонах без виртуальных методов, я просто не совсем понимаю что именно необходимо)

Comment: сейчас сделал 2-мя способами: сначала как у Вас - все работает, потом - через vector<unique_ptr>A> arr, но вот здесь он подчеркивает сам вызов функции в цикле foreach, не подскажите в чем подвох?

Comment: @Koka_LV, смотрите upd1, подвох в том, что нельзя так просто передавать уникальные указатели в сыром виде